# What means to execute `git tag` with the branch name?

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines

In this [bitbucket-pipelines file](https://bitbucket.org/bitbucketpipelines/pushing-a-tag/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml) the tag command looks like this:

```sh
git tag -am "Tagging for release ${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}" release-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}`
```

I understand the use of variables in shell script. What is new to me is the use of what seems to be the branch name in the tag command (`release-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}`).

I'm used to create tag without specifying any branch: `git tag -a v1.0 -m "My v1.0"`

Why would I specify the branch name in the tag command?

I'm assuming `release-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}` is the branch name because the next command in the bitbucket pipelines is a push using this fragment as the branch name:

```sh
git push origin release-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
```

I executed it in my local repo and I noticed my prompt has changed to somewhere I've never been before:

[image: zsh robbyrussell themed shell]

If I execute `git status` I'm still on task/XXXX-251 branch but I didn't get why my prompt changed. If you know oh-my-zsh robbyrussell theme and want to clarify this other part I'd appreciate!

Comment: You probably overlooked that the command in the pipepline starts with : `git tag -am ...` which is the same as `git tag -a -m ...`. On top of that, `git tag` is permissive with the order of its arguments, so taking your example : `git tag -a v1.0 -m "My v1.0"` is the same as `git tag -am "My v1.0" v1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What means to execute `git tag` with the branch name?

`git tag` adds a tag that points to a commit. Branches point to a commit. `git tag <tagname> <branch>` means to tag the commit the branch points to. `git tag <tagname>` without a branch means to tag  current HEAD.

The presented command does **not** use branch name.

```
git tag -am "Tag..." release-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
                                                         ^^^^ - no branch
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - tag name
            ^^^^^^^^ - tag message
          ^          - next argument is a message
```

it's same as, i.e. you can mix flag arguments with positional arguments:

```
git tag -a v1.0 -m "My v1.0"
                   ^^^^^^^^^ - tag message
                ^^           - next argument is a message|
           ^^^^              - tag name
```